# Angular2 issue with This.http.get

Tags: angular, angular2-services, angular2-http

I am beginning to play with Angular 2 and to do so I set up a ASP>NET WebApi hosted locally in IIS at http://localhost:8081/ping (the call returns a string serialized as a JSON Object) which works perfectly well.

This is my service,

```
import { Injectable }    from '@angular/core';
import { Headers, Http } from '@angular/http';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

@Injectable()
export class TempService {

    constructor(
        private http: Http
    ){}

    ping(): Promise<string>{
        return this.http.get('http://localhost:8081/ping')
            .toPromise().then(res => res.json() as string)
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
        alert(error);
        return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
    }
}
```

However, when I attempt to make this call through this function, I get a 200 in the actual call however I get the following error from the handleError function

[image]

I have tried actually deploying the ASP.NET WebApi to an Micrsoft Azure site and it reacts the exact same, and I know for a fact the api is working I just am not sure what is wrong with my service, has this happened to anyone else on here or any ideas on the cause of the issue?

Comment: probably CORS issue

Comment: Your probably right, given that suggestion I opted to try it in a few browsers. It "worked" in Microsoft Edge and IE11, but failed in Chrome (my default), Safari, Opera and Firefox.

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure 'working in Edge' is a good signal or not. AFAIK, for the CORS issue, you have to do some back-end (WebAPI) work to enable CORS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Harry Ninh was correct, once I enabled CORS in my ASP.NET WebApi it began working in all browsers; at least the ones I mentioned in my comment above. Thanks Harry Ninh for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I used to get same issue earlier when i used XHRBackend issue got resolved .

In app.module.ts i have written like following

import { HttpModule, Http, XHRBackend}    from '@angular/http';

@NgModule({.
.
.
 providers: [
        HttpModule, XHRBackend, ..

```
],}
```

)